# File not found error when deploying an azure function (python)

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy an azure function (python) using the command

`func azure functionapp publish APP_NAME --build-native-deps`

which results in the following error:

```
Running 'docker kill aa1945'...........done
Error running docker cp aa19451d487f6790294ffc9435aaff6e57324a20e3ee2edbe4a55c7e98b3fdcb:"/.python_packages/." "C:\Users\**\Documents\*\FuncName\.python_packages".

output: 

open C:\Users\*\FuncName\.python_packages\lib\python3.6\site-packages\azure\mgmt\compute\v2017_03_30\models\__pycache__\virtual_machine_scale_set_public_ip_address_configuration_dns_settings_py3.cpython-36.pyc: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any idea on what could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If anybody encouters the same issue here is what causes it:

The max path length in windows is 259 characters.

The files that are added while building the function can be very long.
E.g. `.python_packages\lib\python3.6\site-packages\azure\mgmt\compute\v2017_03_30\models\__pycache__\virtual_machine_scale_set_public_ip_address_configuration_dns_settings_py3.cpython-36.pyc` already has 184 characters.

I was able to solve this problem by placing the entire folder in `C:\`